# SQL как оптимизировать запрос?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть следующий запрос:

```
SELECT id, slug FROM medicine m WHERE
EXISTS(SELECT medicine_id FROM medicines_components WHERE medicine_id = m.id)
AND EXISTS(
    SELECT id FROM medicine m2 WHERE 
    EXISTS(SELECT medicine_id FROM medicines_countries WHERE medicine_id = m2.id AND country_id = 94)
    AND (SELECT COUNT(medicine_id) FROM medicines_components WHERE medicine_id = m2.id) = (SELECT COUNT(medicine_id) FROM medicines_components WHERE medicine_id = m2.id AND component_id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(component_id SEPARATOR ',') FROM medicines_components WHERE medicine_id = m.id))
)
```

Пример таблицы `medicine`:

```
id | slug
1  | str1
2  | str2
```

Пример таблицы `medicines_components`:

```
medicine_id | component_id
1           | 1
1           | 2
1           | 3
2           | 1
```

Пример таблицы `medicines_countries`:

```
medicine_id | country_id
1           | 1
1           | 2
2           | 1
2           | 3
```

Т.е. суть в том чтобы в таблице `medicine` находить лекарства(записи) у которых есть аналоги с таким же составом(компонентами medicine_components) которые есть в выбранной стране (medicine_countries). Сейчас в таком виде запрос выполняется очень долго, можно ли его как-то оптимизировать?

Comment: Вместо подзапросов используйте JOIN.

Comment: Но мне не нужно в этом запросе объединять данные с каких-то разных таблиц, нужно просто сделать условие по существованию, разве для этого стоит применять JOIN, и будет ли JOIN работать быстрее подзапросов?

Comment: А вы попробуйте =) и да, вас никто не заставляет выбирать эти данные, JOIN просто будет использован как фильтр

Comment: основные тормоза явно из за count. все эти подзапросы выполняются заново для каждой записи исходной таблицы. заранее сгруппировать за один проход и потом переклеить результаты join должно было бы быть в сотни раз быстрее

Comment: А как у вас этот запрос вообще работает ? Вот это `component_id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT` в принципе работать не может. потому что вы сравниваете int со строкой с разделителем запятая. И если у вас скажем group_concat даст строку `'1,5'` то условие IN даст вам только записи с 1, потому что при приведении строки к числу MySQL отбрасывает все что не похоже на цифры. Обратите внимание `x IN(1,5)` это совершенно не то же самое, что `x IN('1,5')` (потому что во втором случае это всего одно значение и оно строка). Ваш group_concat дает вот такую строку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то вам требуется что то в этом роде:

```
SELECT a.slug, a.medicine_id
  FROM (
    SELECT m.slug, c.medicine_id, group_concat(component_id order by component_id) comp
      FROM medicines_components c, medicine m
     WHERE m.id=c.medicine_id
     GROUP BY c.medicine_id, m.slug
  ) a, (
    SELECT c.medicine_id, group_concat(component_id order by component_id) comp
      FROM medicines_components c, medicines_countries co
     WHERE co.medicine_id=c.medicine_id and co.country_id = 1
     GROUP BY c.medicine_id
  ) b where a.medicine_id!=b.medicine_id and a.comp=b.comp
```

Для дальнейшей оптимизации надо смотреть план выполнения запроса на реальных данных и добавлять индексы по необходимости. Если это не помогает, то надо смотреть в сторону внесения избыточности в БД и например хранения списка компонентов в таком виде как его сейчас собирает group_councat но в виде текстового поля в таблице medicine (разумеется в дополнение к таблице medicines_components) с поддержанием правильности этого значения триггерами.